# Laravel: How to set the Primary Key and Foreign Key to string

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm not using the auto increment for the id instead i'm using the 32 char unique id. So when i create a relationship and query, im getting a null because my FK expecting int
my models

```
class User extend Eloquent {
    public $incrementing = false; 
}

class Reservation extend Eloquent {
    public $incrementing = false; 
}
```

so when i query this

```
$reservations = Reservation::with('user')->where('user_id', '=', '22beb4892ba944c8b1895855e1d4d1ad')->get();
i could not retrieve the users information but the reservations info is working fine
when i try to listen for query. eg:
Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($query, $bindings, $time, $name){
    var_dump($query);
    var_dump($bindings);
});
```

i get this

```
string(46) "select * from `reservation` where `user_id` = ?"
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(36) "22beb4892ba944c8b1895855e1d4d1ad"
}
string(53) "select * from `user` where `user`.`id` in (?)"
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  int(0)
}
```

the problem is in the second query i could not retrieve the users info because the user.id expecting int.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, with innoDB you could make those foreing keys without problem

> InnoDB allows a foreign key constraint to reference a non-unique key.
>   This is an InnoDB extension to standard SQL.

Mabe you have your tables wrong, try this

For Reservations

```
    Schema::create('reservations', function($table)
    {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->string('id', 32)->index();
        $table->string('name', 128);
        $table->string('user_id', 32)->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

for users

```
    Schema::create('users', function($table)
    {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->string('id', 32)->index();
        $table->string('name', 128);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

then you need to create the relationship in reservations

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id');
}
```

and now when you search

```
$reservations = Reservation::with('user')->where('user_id', '=', '22beb4892ba944c8b1895855e1d4d1ad')->get();
```

it must work! i've tested this code.

Comment: great! it works! just need to put on 2nd param `user_id` from my `$this->belongsTo('User')`. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

In newer versions of Laravel (Im using 6.5.1) you have to set up the key type to string (By default PK type is set to integer)

Following the example of the question:

```
class User extend Eloquent {
    public $incrementing = false; 
    public $keyType = 'string';
}

class Reservation extend Eloquent {
    public $incrementing = false;
    public $keyType = 'string'; 
}
```

You can see the example in the [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#defining-models)

Comment: This method does not involve changing the engine of a table to InnoDB. Works in my Laravel 5.8.* project.