# laravel foreign key for string type (null issue)

Tags: php, string, laravel, null, key

I'm trying to get(then display) the creator/author name with foreign key in articles table from users table. I'm merely new with laravel I hope you can help me out with that issue. I have no issue with int type F-key(s) but with string types I'm probably missing something somewhere. Sometimes it's giving me some errors sometimes everything works fine but user_name on articles table is just staying null.
If you need more info about something please leave a comment.
Thanks in advance!

> article's Schema

```
Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
      $table->string('user_name')->nullable();
      $table->string('title');
      $table->text('body');
      $table->timestamps();
      $table->timestamp('published_at');

      $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

      $table->foreign('user_name')
            ->references('name')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
  });
```

> user's Schema

```
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: Check this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22692054/laravel-how-to-set-the-primary-key-and-foreign-key-to-string

Comment: Using eloquent is another way and it is easy

Answer (score 0):

Do not save the user name in the article.
You only save the user id and create the relation in the models like

```
class User extends Model {
  public function articles() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Article');
  }
}

class Article extends Model {
  public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
  }
}
```

If your relations are correct set up you can access the username like this:

```
$article->user->name
```

In the other direction you can a users articles with:

```
$user->articles
```

Note: The relations are handled like properties and not like functions.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be...

1. remove user_name from the article.  Let the user_id lead to user data.
2. use laravel's built in User class which extends Model
3. make an article class to extend Model
4. setup relationships between them

App/User.php

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use ...

class User extends ...{

    public function Articles(){
        return $this->hasMany(Articles::class)
    }
}
```

App/Article.php
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

```
namespace App;
class Article extends Model{
    public function User(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    public function getAuthorAttribute(){
        return $this->User->name;
    }
}
```

Now you can access data as...

```
$user->Articles;
$article->User
$article->author
```

To refine access, you can get the query builder by calling any relationship as a function.

```
$user->Articles()->where('title, 'like', 'cars')->get()
```

To look at what's going on...

```
$user->Articles()->where('title, 'like', 'cars')->toSql()
```