# Laravel Auth::user()->id returns 0 on custom id

Tags: laravel, laravel-authentication

I am trying to make a User object with a String as ID. Everything went fine, even authenticating. But whenever I am trying to get the currently logged in user his ID by either:

```
Auth::user()->id
```

or

```
Auth::id();
```

Both are returning '0'. Whenever I dump the Auth::user object I can actually see the id attribute correctly. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel: How to set the Primary Key and Foreign Key to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22692054/laravel-how-to-set-the-primary-key-and-foreign-key-to-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Laravel` tries to cast it to integer, simply put the following property in your `User` class.

```
class User {
    public $incrementing = false; 
}
```