# Trying to use string as foreign key in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, innodb

I am just a beginner and trying to use string as foreign key in laravel but getting this error while fetching the data:-

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'read' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `from` as sender_id, count(`from`) as messages_count from `messages` where `to` = d3c364bb-0982-46ba-869a-24dbb2c50aea and `read` = 0 group by `from`)

In here I am fetching users contacts from received and a group of unread message count

```
public function get(){
        $contacts = DB::table('received')
    ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->uuid)
    ->get();
    
     $unreadIds = Message::select(\DB::raw('`from` as sender_id, count(`from`) as messages_count'))
            ->where('to', Auth::user()->uuid)
            ->where('read', false)
            ->groupBy('from')
            ->get();

       
        $contacts = $contacts->map(function($contact) use ($unreadIds) {
            $contactUnread = $unreadIds->where('sender_id', $contact->friends_id)->first();

            $contact->unread = $contactUnread ? $contactUnread->messages_count : 0;

            return $contact;
        });

    return response()->json($contacts);
        }
```

**Received Table:-**

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('received', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->id();
            $table->string('user_id', 36);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('friends_id');
            $table->string('list_no')->nullable();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

This is from where i am fetching unread message count:-

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->boolean('read')->after('to', 36)->default(false);
        });
    }

    
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('read');
        });
    }
```

**Here's Message table**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->id();
            $table->string('from', 36);
            $table->string('to', 36);
            $table->text('text');   
            $table->string('list_no')->nullable(); 
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Can anyone please help me through this.

Comment: The "from" is a reserved expression in SQL, not recommended the use it as field name!
+ I found a typo here in the table name: `Schema::create('recieveds', function (Blueprint $table) {`

Comment: @AdamP. That typo was made while I was typing this question, ``from`` was working perfectly fine when I wasn't using string as foreign key

Comment: I suggest reading about [Eloquent Relationshops](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships). Not sure why you are defining engine in your migrations. What version MySQL and Laravel? Default in MySQL now is InnoDB so that shouldn't be needed.

Comment: @mikeroq I am using laravel 8 and I saw this method on [this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22692054/laravel-how-to-set-the-primary-key-and-foreign-key-to-string)

Comment: @KakashiHatake if you notice on that question it was from 2014. It's been quite a long time in Laravel development.

Comment: @mikeroq yes you are right, So what should I do to solve this problem, got any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking closely at the sql error: the query formed is using "from" initially without any table name because you have used "from" as a **column** name which is SQL keyword for making queries.

Try a different column name may be "from_user" instead of "from" in your message table migrations and refresh the migrations to reflect changes in DB.

Also make the relevant column name changes in the code as well.

Note- Instead of changing old migration, you can also change the column name by creating a new migration and adding `$table->renameColumn('from', 'from_user');`

Comment: It says nothing to migrate can you provide another answer please