# Column id has varchar string data in MySQL table but Laravel response shows 0

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a table in MySQL with id column (type varchar) as primary:

[image]

and filled table:

[image]

I use Laravel for backend. I created Model for this table and put this code inside Model class:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'titleEn',
    'titleFa',
    'icon',
    'sortOrder',
];
```

And in the controller.index, I have:

```
$categories = CategoryModel::all();
return $categories;
```

When I call this API, the response shows 0 value for id instead of real value:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "titleEn": "Computer",
    "titleFa": "کامپیوتر",
    "icon": "",
    "sortOrder": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 0,
    "titleEn": "Novel",
    "titleFa": "رمان و داستان",
    "icon": "",
    "sortOrder": 1
  }
]
```

What is the problem an how can I deal with without renaming id to another name? Thanks.

**Note:**

In my case, primary key is id with different datatype.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582535/laravel-5-2-use-a-string-as-a-custom-primary-key-for-eloquent-table-becomes-0 ?

Comment: The duplicate says Laravel 5.2, but [it's still valid through the current version (11)](https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent#primary-keys)

Comment: @Álvaro González and aynber Thanks. Your suggestion is not exactly my answer but it helped me. In your suggestion, user asked for another primary column with different name from id. But in my case, I have id with different datatype. It is solved using casts function in Model. Thanks all.

Comment: Perhaps a better duplicate target, but the answer is the same. [Laravel: How to set the Primary Key and Foreign Key to string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59499858/1255289)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do one think .. define the keyType as string in modal. Which you are using. it will automatically accept the string primary key.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent

```
<?php
 
class CategoryModel extends Model
{
    /**
     * The "type" of the auto-incrementing ID.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $keyType = 'string';
}
```

Comment: Welcome @Tilak_Singh. Your answer is better and clearer than mine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I added note in my question, In my case, primary key is id with different datatype. But suggested links by my friends is about another primary column with different name from id (Thanks).

The suggested links helped me to solve the problem. I used casts function in Model:

```
protected function casts(): array
{
    return [
        'id' => 'string',
    ];
}
```

I posted it for helping other users (I hope!)